# Weierstrass theorem for holomorphic function.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show that function $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(z-n)^2}{n^4}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$. I think, that I should to apply Weierstrass Theorem. Unfortunately I have no idea. I was thinking about creating a sequence $f_k=\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{(z-n)^2}{n^4}$.

Comment: This doesn't even converge as $(z-n)^n/n^4$ doesn't go to $0$

Comment: I am sorry. I made mistake. Should be $(z-n)^2$

Comment: In this case Weierstraß Theorem works. Remember that you only need to show *compact* convergence of the series, i.e. if you want to majorize the terms $\frac{(z-n)^2}{n^4}$ we may assume $|z|<C$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: For fixed $z$ and large $n$ you roughly have $\sum 1/n^2$, which converges. Can you make that into a proof?

Comment: The Weierstrass, and even [Stone-Weiestrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone–Weierstrass_theorem), Theorems are based on the premise that the domain of the function is a compact Hausdorff space.  The complex plane is certainly Hausdorff, but it is not compact.  Furthermore, these theorems give only the *continuity* of the function in question, which is a much weaker requirement than holomorphicity.

You might also want to see section 2.1 in [Morera's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem#Uniform_limits), which also operates on compact sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an outline: choose $R>0$ and for $\lvert z\rvert\le R$ apply the bound $\lvert z-n\rvert^2\le (R+n)^2$ to get
$$
\lvert f(z)\rvert\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(R+n)^2}{n^4}<\infty.
$$
You can prove that the above expression is finite by expanding the numerator and comparing with $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$. Then you have shown convergence for $\lvert z\rvert\le R$ by the $M-$test. This will hold for any fixed $R$ and so $f(z)$ converges for all $z\in \Bbb{C}$.